# Is “are just can't” correct?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> Some curves are just can't be flattened.

Shouldn't it just be "Some curves just can't be flattened"?

Asking for corrections and suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like an error to me. I suspect that the writer originally typed something like "some curves are just incapable of being flattened" a then intended to edit it to "some curves just can't be flattened" but only overwrote "incapable of being" and forgot to delete "are". People, including me, do this all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, "are" is too much.

- Some curves just can't be flattened.

There is the possibility "Some curves are just flattened.", but then one would wonder at the reason of  this "can't be", which is even more incongruous.